# How to type TAB in QLineEdit?

Tags: qt, qt5, qlineedit

When I type tab in QLineEdit, I go to the next widget. How to disable this behavior and type the TAB character in the QLineEdit box?

Comment: You can install an even filter on your line edit and handle key release events alternatively.

Comment: Or consider to use QTextEdit

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the keys via handle:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
     if (obj == m_lineEdit) 
     {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress) 
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);

            if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
            {
                //do here
                return true;
            }             
     }

        //return event to the parent class
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Or you can create your own class inherited from QLineEdit and overload the method:

```
void LineEdit::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent* event)
{
     if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
     {
        emit tabPressed();
        return;
     }

     QLineEdit::keyPressEvent(event);
}
```